# create new SparkSession for different query?

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'd like to get two data from elasticsearch

One is filtered with a query, another has no filter.

```
 // with query
 session = get_spark_session(query=query)

 df = session.read.option(
     "es.resource", "analytics-prod-2019.08.02"
 ).format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load()


 df.show() // empty result

 // without query
 session = get_spark_session()

 df = session.read.option(
     "es.resource", "analytics-prod-2019.08.02"
 ).format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load()

 df.show() // empty result


 def get_spark_session(query=None, excludes=[]):

     conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
     conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
     conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
     conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "true")
     conf.set("es.scroll.size", 10000)
     conf.set("es.read.field.exclude", excludes)
     conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/elasticsearch-hadoop/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.6.2.jar")
     if query:
         conf.set("es.query", query)


     sc = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

     return sc
```

The question is whether the session is reused or not..

When I run `filtered` query first, and `non-filtered` query second, 
both gives empty result

But when I run `non-filtered` query first, it shows some results, and the subsequent `filtered` query shows empty result.

```
 // below, I reverse the order
 // without query
 session = get_spark_session()

 df = session.read.option(
     "es.resource", "analytics-prod-2019.08.02"
 ).format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load()

 df.show() // some result

 // with query
 session = get_spark_session(query=query)

 df = session.read.option(
     "es.resource", "analytics-prod-2019.08.02"
 ).format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load()


 df.show() // empty result
```

** edit

So I can get desired result with the following:

```
def get_spark_session(query=None, excludes=[]):

    conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
    conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
    conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "true")
    conf.set("es.scroll.size", 10000)
    conf.set("es.read.field.exclude", excludes)
    conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/elasticsearch-hadoop/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.6.2.jar")
    if query:
        conf.set("es.query", query)
    else:
        conf.set("es.query", "") # unset the query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SparkSession.builder gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one based on the options set in this builder. In your case, spark config is being reused. Removing "es.query" from config should fix this:

```
def get_spark_session(query=None, excludes=[]):
     conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
     conf.unset("es.query")
     conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
     conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
     conf.set("es.nodes.discovery", "true")
     conf.set("es.scroll.size", 10000)
     conf.set("es.read.field.exclude", excludes)
     conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/elasticsearch-hadoop/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-6.6.2.jar")
     if query:
         conf.set("es.query", query)    

     sc = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()    
     return sc
```

Comment: So how do I get one dataset `with` query and `without` query?

Comment: when you run the filtered query first, the query is set in conf. Since the query is part of the conf it is reused when you query for non-filtered dataset.